# Testing Vue components that utilize cytoscape.js?

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2, jestjs, cytoscape.js, vue-test-utils

I am working on something that involves cytoscape.js and Vue.js. I am currently using jest.js for unit testing the Vue components. A lot of my components have their funtionality tied to a cytoscape graph that is mounted on a container.

This is how my test files look like:

```
import graph from "@/graph.vue"

import {
    mount,
    createLocalVue,
} from "@vue/test-utils"

const localVue = createLocalVue();

describe('graph.vue', () => {

    it('should center the graph', () =>{
        const wrapper = mount(graph, {
            localVue,
        })
        const button = wrapper.find('btn')
        expect(wrapper.vm.Cytoscape())).toHaveBeenCalled(0)
        button.trigger('click')
        expect(wrapper.vm.Cytoscape()).toHaveBeenCalled(1)
    })
})
```

If it uses any cytoscape, it gives the following error:

```
Cannot read property 'className' of null

      11 | // run(): Startup-Function
      12 | export function run() {
    > 13 |   cy = cytoscape({
         |        ^
      14 | 
      15 |     container: document.getElementById('cy'), // container to render in
      16 |     //builds graph 
      17 | }
```

I suspect that I have the wrong approach or even testing environment for this. What am I missing ?

Edit: I have found an alternative solution to the problem. Instead of unit testing with jest, there are many things that I needed to test that I could also test in E2E testing. I currently use Cypress to do that.

Comment: what is the error? You may need to mock canvas when using jest. See for example https://www.npmjs.com/package/jest-canvas-mock